# Array object is not getting updated after the http service call

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, http

I am working on a scenario where i have to retrieve a list of objects from springboot using rest calls and populate them into the UI using angular 5.

my component looks like this,

```
export class BusinessComponent implements OnInit {

  serviceSavings:Services[] = [];

  constructor(private ServicesService:ServicesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ServicesService.getServicesByCatID(PRODUCTSAVINGSID)
      .subscribe(serviceSavings => this.serviceSavings = serviceSavings);

    console.log("The length of serviceSavings :", this.serviceSavings.length); //this always prints zero.
  }

  examplemethod() {
    console.log("The length of serviceSavings :", this.serviceSavings.length);
  }
}
```

Now the problem is the log statement inside init() methods prints 0 rows of the service. i need to retrieve each service from the list and perform some actions on it.

The same log when i placed in a user defined method like calling it with user action in the UI. it displays the exact number of count of the list as per in the database table.

I need to write some business logic inside init() during the application load to display certain values in UI.

but the length of the list retrived is always 0 in init() while application load. i am not able to iterate through values. i think there is some update issue of the arrayobject.

my service method looks like this,

```
  getServicesByCatID(categoryid){
    return this.http.get(this.getServiceUrlByCategory(categoryid))
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

the springboot application is perfectly return the list of objects there is no problem from the backend.

could someone please help me in finding out the issue ?

Comment: What's `PRODUCTSAVINGSID`? And if you look in `network` in the console of chrome or something can you actually see any results?

Comment: You should put your console.log inside the return of the subscribe

Comment: productSavingsID is a int value which i did not mention here but i did in the code. yes, i checked in the chrome the log statements are getting printed but its 0 in init log always

Comment: @HMarteau : thats the samething i did..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226919/fetching-data-from-rest-web-service-using-angular-2-http/49026024#49026024

Answer (score 2):

move your console inside the `subscribe()`

```
ngOnInit(){

this.ServicesService.getServicesByCatID(PRODUCTSAVINGSID) 
.subscribe(serviceSavings => {this.serviceSavings = serviceSavings

  console.log("The length of serviceSavings :", this.serviceSavings.length)

  });

}
```

Comment: i dont know how this happened but i tried just now..its getting printed..the question is i need to do another restcall with the ID in serviceSavings. it becomes complicated if i nest it inside this..

Comment: @ChandraMouli if it is not printed that means you are never coming back from the service. And you do not need  `.map(res => res.json());` anymore

Comment: instead, write this `this.serviceSavings = [...serviceSavings]` see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get the result before subscription finish, move it inside subscribe; and if you want to get this data in the view, you can use async Pipe for that:

```
export class BusinessComponent implements OnInit {
 serviceSavings : Observable<Services[]>;

constructor(private ServicesService: ServicesService){}

ngOnInit(){
 this.serviceSavings = 
  this.ServicesService.getServicesByCatID(PRODUCTSAVINGSID); 
}
```

and you can iterate over your data in the view:

```
<p *ngFor='let service of serviceSavings | async'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue and I came to a conclusion that One should write this

```
 this.ServicesService.getServicesByCatID(PRODUCTSAVINGSID)
 .subscribe(serviceSavings => this.serviceSavings = [...serviceSavings]);
```

instead of `this.serviceSavings = serviceSavings` and the same way, each time you wish to add an element to an array, you'd better write `this.serviceSavings = [...serviceSavings, newServiceSaving]` instead of `.push(newServiceSaving)`